# Normalising series data of variable length

Tags: mean, normalization, standardization, recursive-model

I have a model `m` which takes as input a starting array of `n_input` elements which are actually traces of mining processes and outputs an array of `n_pred` predictions along with their probabilities . This works iteratively, and so the model would use these predictions one after the other and append it to the input to use it as input for the model again. This continues until an `End` token is reached.

So, I am getting ordered traces along with the probabilities of the next element at each step. This can be visualised as a Decision Tree as well. But now, since all these traces are of variable length, I want to find a way to normalise and accumulate their probabilities an then compare them.

I was trying to multiply the probabilities and then diving them by the length of the array, but this was punishing the longer arrays. Is there any better way to normalise these lists of probabilities of variable length?

Comment: Viterbi algorithm?

Comment: @Sycorax Thank you so much for this answer. I'm looking into it.